# exact word fulltext search postgresql

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, exact-match

Postgresql fulltext search match nearby words, but i want to search the exact word in large content table (thousands of words in hundreds of thousands of lines). 
My search must be very fast (less than a second).
Using like or ilike is to slow( with 200000 words: more than 5 seconds).
Does anyone have a query to advise me?

Comment: Please clarify why PostgreSQL full text search does not fit the bill.

Comment: because if i search "servant" for example, postgresql full text search also match "server", but in my case i want that postgresql only match the exact word "servant", and not nearby words like "server" or other.

Comment: Oh, that's simple. Just use a dictionary that does *not* apply stemming.

Comment: How can I do that? have you an exemple? I use french dictionnary but an english dictionnary with good explanation could help me.

Comment: I have my own dictionary using this article some adaptations
http://shisaa.jp/postset/postgresql-full-text-search-part-2.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to solve your problem with PostgreSQL full text search if you use the `simple` dictionary and create an appropriate GIN index:

```
CREATE TABLE haystack (id serial PRIMARY KEY, string text NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO haystack (string) VALUES ('I am your servant');
INSERT INTO haystack (string) VALUES ('What use is a server without a client?');

CREATE INDEX haystack_fts_ind ON haystack USING gin (to_tsvector('simple', string));
```

Let's disable sequential scans so the index is used, even though the example table is too small:

```
SET enable_seqscan=off;
```

Now only exact matches are found, and no stemming takes place:

```
SELECT * FROM haystack
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', string) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'servant');

 id |      string       
----+-------------------
  1 | I am your servant
(1 row)
```

The index can be used to speed up the query:

```
EXPLAIN (COSTS off) SELECT * FROM haystack
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', string) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'servant');

                                        QUERY PLAN                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on haystack
   Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, string) @@ '''servant'''::tsquery)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on haystack_fts_ind
         Index Cond: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, string) @@ '''servant'''::tsquery)
(4 rows)
```